# Page not working after changing .html file to .php file in a laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

some time ago i made a memory game using javascript and jquery. now i'm trying to create a new website with Laravel and display all my projects there.

but when i put the contents of the html file in a .blade.php it doesn't load any of the css or js, just the text in the .blade.php file itself.

i'm probably doing something stupid but i'm new to all this.
anyway i don't know how to fix it.

the html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Memorygame.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <center><div id="kaas">Memory Game</div></center>
        <div class="container" id="container" onclick="Time()">
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile0" onclick="matchThis(0)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile1" onclick="matchThis(1)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile2" onclick="matchThis(2)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile3" onclick="matchThis(3)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile4" onclick="matchThis(4)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile5" onclick="matchThis(5)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile6" onclick="matchThis(6)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile7" onclick="matchThis(7)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile8" onclick="matchThis(8)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile9" onclick="matchThis(9)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile10" onclick="matchThis(10)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile11" onclick="matchThis(11)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile12" onclick="matchThis(12)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile13" onclick="matchThis(13)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile14" onclick="matchThis(14)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile15" onclick="matchThis(15)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile16" onclick="matchThis(16)"></div>
            <div class="mem"><img src="think.jpg" id="tile17" onclick="matchThis(17)"></div>
        </div>
        <audio id="dankmeme">
          <source src="macintoshplus.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>


        <div id="try">Tries: 0</div>
        <div id="moves">Score: 0</div>
        <div id="time">Time 0:00</div>
        <button id="knomp" onclick="Buttonpressyeah();"> New Game </button><br />
        <button id="home" onclick="gohome();">Home</button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Memorygame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

the css:

```
#kaas {
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    color: #33CCCC;
    font-size: 80;
    font-family: broadway;
}

body {
    background: url(backg.gif) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#container {
    height: 492px;
    width: 972px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

div.container {
    display: none
}


#knomp {
    position: relative;
    top:-430px;
    background: #def2ff;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6;
    -moz-border-radius: 6;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 0px;
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: #6e6b6e;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#knomp:hover {
    background: #a1d6f7;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#home {
  position: relative;
  top:-420px;
  background: #def2ff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #def2ff, #ffb5b5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #6e6b6e;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#home:hover {
    background: #a1d6f7;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #a1d6f7, #d17777);
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#try {
  width:110px;
  position: relative;
  top:-480px;
  background: #084b78;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


#moves {
  width:110px;
  position: relative;
  top:-475px;
  background: #084b78;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #084b78, #fa23ec);
    -webkit-border-radius: 6;
    -moz-border-radius: 6;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: Courier New;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#time {
  width:110px;
  position: relative;
  top:-470px;
  background: #084b78;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #084b78, #fa23ec);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6;
  -moz-border-radius: 6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mem {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

#winner {
  content:url(winnerpic.jpg);
  position: relative;
  left:230px;
}
```

and the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('div.container').slideDown(500).removeClass('container');
});

$(function(){
  $(".mem").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1).fadeIn(400).removeClass(".mem");
  })
});

function shuffleArray(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
  }
 return array;
}


var speelbord = ['pepe1.png','pepe1.png','pepe2.png','pepe2.png',
    'pepe3.png','pepe3.png','pepe4.png','pepe4.png','pepe5.png','pepe5.png',
    'pepe6.png','pepe6.png','pepe7.png','pepe7.png','pepe8.png','pepe8.png',
    'pepe9.png','pepe9.png'];

speelbord = shuffleArray(speelbord);

var aangeklikt = [];

var kaasjes = [];

var stop = 0;



function matchThis(index) {
  var img = document.getElementById("tile" + index);

  if(img.getAttribute("src") == 'think.jpg' && aangeklikt.length < 2) {
    img.src = speelbord[index];
    aangeklikt.push(index);
    checkTiles();
  }
}


function turnbackTiles() {
  var img1 = document.getElementById("tile" + aangeklikt[0]);
  var img2 = document.getElementById("tile" + aangeklikt[1]);

  img1.src = "think.jpg";
  img2.src = "think.jpg";

  aangeklikt = [];
}

var punt = 0;
var probeer = 0;

function checkTiles() {
  if(kaasjes.includes(aangeklikt[0] && aangeklikt[1])) {
    return false;
  }
    if(aangeklikt.length == 2) {
      stop = 1;
      if(speelbord[aangeklikt[0]] != speelbord[aangeklikt[1]]) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          turnbackTiles();
          probeer++;
          document.getElementById("try").innerHTML = "Tries: " + probeer;
        }, 500);
        setTimeout(function() {
          stop = 0;
        },600);

      }
      else {
        aangeklikt = [];
        punt++;
        document.getElementById("moves").innerHTML = "Score: " + punt;
    }
  }
}


var audiopiece = document.getElementById("dankmeme");
var doubly = 0;

function Time() {
  if (punt == 9) {
    clearInterval(start);
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = "<div id='winner'></div>";
    audiopiece.play();
  }

  if (doubly == 0) {
    doubly++
    start = setInterval(function() {sec()}, 1000)
  }
}

var seconde = 0;
var minuten = 0;
var extra = "00";

function sec() {
  seconde=seconde+1;

  var seconde1 = "" + seconde
  var seconde2 = extra.substring(0,extra.length - seconde1.length) + seconde1

  if (seconde == 60) {
    seconde=seconde-60;
    minuten=minuten+1;
    seconde2 = "00"
  }
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Time: " + minuten + ":" + seconde2;
}

function Buttonpressyeah() {
  location.reload();
}

function gohome() {
  window.location.href = "index.html";
}
```

Comment: learn about laravel before jumping directly into

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In laravel all css and javascript file you have to add it inside public folder

for example if you created css folder inside public folder then you have to include like this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
```

for js also same think .for example if you have added all js files inside js folder then

```
<script src="{{asset('js/sweetalert.min.js')}}"></script>
```

you can read few helpers functions in official documentation
Ref:
 https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-asset

for blade template ref: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

Comment: Thanks! that worked. it's weird though, because with another project i could just link to the public css folder file with href="/css/filename.css"

Answer (score 1):

In laravel you have create css/js folder(s) inside the public folder then you have to include files like this:

For CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/your-filename.css')}}">
```

For JS:

```
<script src="{{asset('js/your-filename.js')}}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use absolute path of css/js. They will be relative to your public directory. Let's assume your js is in public/js:

```
<script src="/js/Memorygame.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```